# Ошибка с использованием структуры

Tags: c, pthread

В данной программе нужно вычесть определенный интеграл используя потоки:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define cntThreads 4

pthread_mutex_t mutexReduction;

double integral=0;

struct ArgsThread
{
    int left,right;
    double step;
};

void * worker(void * args)
{

    struct ArgsThread AT;
    double x;
    double sum=0;
    double step=AT.step;
    long i;
    for (i=AT.left; i< AT.right; i++)
    {
        x = (AT.left + AT.step *(i+0.5));
        sum = sum + (x*x)/2;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexReduction);
    integral += sum*step;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexReduction);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num_steps=50;    

    pthread_t threads[cntThreads];
    int ArgsThread [cntThreads];
    printf("number of threads = %d\n", cntThreads);
    double step = 1/(double)num_steps;
    long cntStepsPerThread= num_steps / cntThreads;
    int idThread;

    for (idThread=0; idThread<cntThreads; idThread++)
    {
        ArgsThread[idThread].left  = idThread*cntStepsPerThread;
        ArgsThread[idThread].right = (idThread+1)*cntStepsPerThread;
        ArgsThread[idThread].step = step;
        if (pthread_create(&threads[idThread], NULL, worker, &ArgsThread[idThread]) != 0)
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (idThread=0; idThread<cntThreads; idThread++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(threads[idThread], NULL) != 0)
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("The value of Integral is %f\n ", integral);
    return 0;
}
```

Программа не компилируется. Получаю три ошибки

*request for member 'left* (right, step)' *in something not structure or union*

в этой части кода:

```
ArgsThread[idThread].left  = idThread*cntStepsPerThread;
ArgsThread[idThread].right = (idThread+1)*cntStepsPerThread;
ArgsThread[idThread].step = step;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так, как можно исправить?

Comment: Не понял. У вас `ArgsThread` объявлено как массив `int`. О каком `ArgsThread[idThread].left` может идти речь для обычного `int`? Почему вы объявили этот массив как массив `int`?

Comment: @AnT, нужно сделать с помощью указателя? Не совсем понимаю как объявить.

Comment: У вас объявление массива ArgsThread накладывается на объявление структуры ArgsThread, Если вы полагаете, что таким образом объявили массив структур, то вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: @yashi: Никакого указателя. По коду ясно видно, что вам нужен массив элементов типа `struct ArgsThread`. Вы же объявили  массив элементов типа `int`. Если вы не понимаете, о чем идет речь, то я не понимаю, как вы сумели написать остальной код.

Comment: @freim: В языке С ничего никуда не накладывается. Тэги структур и имена переменных находятся в независимых пространствах имен. Структура называется `struct ArgsThread`. Переменная называется `ArgsThread`. Объявлением переменной с именем `ArgsThread` вы ничего не "накладываете" на имя типа `struct ArgsThread`.

Comment: @AnT, мне вот интересно- вы в самом деле не поняли о чем я писал, или просто захотелось докопаться?

Comment: @freim, спасибо, все понял, сам не увидел что написал.

Comment: @freim: Нет, "действительно не понял". Что же вы имели в виду под вашим "объявление массива ArgsThread накладывается на объявление структуры ArgsThread"?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, вместо строки

```
int ArgsThread [cntThreads];
```

надо написать нечто вроде:

```
struct ArgsThread xyz[cntThreads];
```

Соответственно, исправить присвоения:

```
xyz[idThread].left  = idThread*cntStepsPerThread;
xyz[idThread].right = (idThread+1)*cntStepsPerThread;
xyz[idThread].step = step;

if (pthread_create(&threads[idThread], NULL, worker, &xyz[idThread]) != 0)
```